# Modifying an existing data set

Tags: r

Suppose we have a 100 by 100 data set of numbers. We want to transform it by taking the logarithm of all of the numbers. In R, how would you do this?

Comment: Start here: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf

Answer (score 11):

First, let's make some example data. I have made a 100 x 100 matrix filled with positive random numbers.

```
## Save the fake data into the object called "Data"
> Data <- matrix(abs(rnorm(10000)),100,100)

## We can confirm the dimensions of the matrix like so
> dim(Data)
[1] 100 100

## We can confirm that it is a matrix like so
> class(Data)
[1] "matrix"

## We can take a peak at rows 1 to 5 and columns 1 to 2 like so
> Data[1:5,1:2]
          [,1]        [,2]
[1,] 1.5814281 0.216556739
[2,] 0.8939682 0.007296336
[3,] 1.7937537 0.955205600
[4,] 0.4994752 1.982777723
[5,] 1.3459607 1.328990348
```

Now let's take the logarithm of these numbers and save it as a new object.

```
## First we can take the natural log and save it in the object "Natural"
Natural <- log(Data)

## Or we can take the log base 10 and save it in the object "Base10"
Base10 <- log10(Data)

## To see all of the objects in your working memory, we can type the following
ls()
```

Hope this helps! If you need more help with R basics try these websites:

1. http://www.r-tutor.com/
2. http://twitter.com/#!/RLangTip

Comment: The two links at the bottom are quite worthwhile.